# In a Wordpress installation, JQuery simple script does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, class, enqueue

I have a wordpress website and i want to add a class "myclass" to all anchor elements with JQuery.
This wordpress installation does not have any plugin enabled, so its a default installation.

I enqueue TEST.js file with the following command at the bottom of the functions.php file of my theme (Hello Elementor)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Explicitly telling wordpress to load jquery
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'fixamea', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/TEST.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery')
    );
}
```

And the file TEST.js is the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    $('a').addClass('myclass');
    console.log("running");


})
```

The console log "running" appears but the class 'myclass' is not added to any Anchor elements.
What could be wrong?

Comment: What happens instead? Are you facing any error message? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with $. try to log and see the content of this $.

Comment: what is the error in console?